# REST how to pass empty path parameter in the URI?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I am developing a restful webapp.
In this the parameters i take are userid and orderid.

The `userid` can be `null`.
The URI is `@Path("api/user/userid/order/orderid")`
My method is,

```
void add(@PathParam("userid") String userId, @PathParam("orderid") String orderId);
```

I want to pass null value for `userId` in the URI.

I tried `api/user//order/1234`. But in this case, the `userid` takes the value of `orderId` (i.e 1234 and `orderId` is `null`. (which is wrong)

I also tried changing the path as `@Path("api/user/userid: .*/order/orderid")`. Yet the same result as previous.

The other ways for solving this could be, using `@QueryParam` for `userid` or creating another method for `userid null`.

But I would like to know if there is a way to have `userId` as `PathParameter` instead of `QueryParam` and pass the value of `userid` as `null`?

Comment: Why can the userid be null?  What is your app going to do if it is null?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having a URL param as null is not a valid case.

POSTing to the URL `api/user/userid/order/orderid` is saying "create an order for this user". GETting to that same URL would be saying "retrieve me this specific order for this user". Both are in the context of a user.

For doing order creation or retrieval outside of the context of a user, just remove those two parts of your URL...

```
api/order/orderid
```

This would allow you to create and get orders outside of the bounds of a customer. This would also work for in the context of a user. If you POST an order with no userID, nobody cares, but one can be specified. And if you GET an order, it shouldn't care which customer it is for, unless your orderID isn't unique across customers but that is probably not a good idea but that is a separate discussion.