# How to pass null value in RESTful web service for a GET Method?

Tags: rest, get, null, cxf, jax-rs

I Currently have a **RESTFul** web Service exposed using **CXF**. The Method looks like this.

```
@GET
@Path("/getProfile/{memberno}/{userid}/{channelid}")
@Consumes("application/xml")
public MaintainCustomerProductResponse getUserDetails(
        @PathParam("memberno") String membernumber,
        @PathParam("userid") String userid,
        @PathParam("channelid") String channelid){
//DO Some Logic here.
}
```

This can be accessed via following URL & on submitting valid data I get response.

```
http://server.com:8080/UserService/getProfile/{memberno}/{userid}/{channelid}
```

Question: How can I pass null value for `userid` ?

If I simple ignore the `{userId}` the request is'nt hitting on the server side web service.

Example

```
http://server.com:8080/UserService/getProfile/1001//1
```

Note: I'm using `SOAPUi` for Testing and without giving `userId` value I see following response on `SOAPUI` and Request doesn't hit the server.

SOAPUI Response

```
<data contentType="null" contentLength="0"><![CDATA[]]></data>
```

Answer (score 7):

The default match of a variable is `[^/]+?` (at least one character) you can manually set the match to `[^/]*?` and it should also match empty strings.

Just add the format to the userid variable:

```
@Path("/getProfile/{memberno}/{userid: [^/]*?}/{channelid}")
```

Comment: Thanks Aviram, This helps me to proceed one step Ahead.
But if I submit the request with no userid I see that the on the server side the value of channelid is considered as userid and channelId is null.

I can rearrange the parameter and get my job done but is it possible to have same order of parameter on server side and still pass null or empty string to userid ?

Comment: There might be a problem because I didn't put a space after `userid:` can you try adding the space the see what happens ?

Comment: Without space it worked! I mean it allowed me to send "" (emptystring) which I assume/convert that into null on server side.

BUT on Submitting below url to server. What's happening is 
FirstParameter = membernumber is taking 51
SecondParameter = userId is taking 1 and
ThirdParameter = channelId is taking null.

I.e., the channelID (3rd parameter) is mapped to userId (Second Parameter) if null or emptyString (51//1) is passed.

boardingservice/comint/webservice/getProfile/51//1 

Somthing like below
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266349/rest-how-to-pass-empty-path-parameter-in-the-uri

Comment: I got that, but what does it do without the space ? i read somewhere it could have an effect

Answer (score 2):

Please change `@Path("/getProfile/{memberno}/{userid}/{channelid}")`
 `@Path("/getProfile/{memberno}/{userid = default}/{channelid}")` so that it will accept null values  to user id .  You can use Uri templates to specify default values for optional parameters.Please refer

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675245.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved with a Work Around. I created another Method that takes only two parameter. Now Based on Request URL different method is called

Answer (score 0):

```
@GET
@Path("qwer/{z}&{x:.*?}&{c}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String withNullableX(
        @PathParam("z") Integer z,
        @PathParam("x") Integer x,
        @PathParam("c") Integer c
) {
    return z + "" + x + "" + c;
}
```

When you call with
http://localhost:8080/asdf/qwer/1&&3
you will see:
`1null3`

Answer (score 0):

You could use URL encoding, pass `%00`. Refer [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

Example: `http://server.com:8080/UserService/getProfile/1001/%00/1`

Answer (score 0):

There is needed more detailed describe all cases, which are possible. Look on the exapmple based on Spring Framework:

```
        @RestController
        @RequestMapping("/misc")
        public class MiscRestController {
    ...
            @RequestMapping(value = { "/getevidencecounts/{userId}",
                    "/getevidencecounts/{userId}/{utvarVSId = default}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
            public ResponseEntity<EvidenceDokumentuCountTO> getEvidenceCounts(
                    @PathVariable(value = "userId", required = true) Long userId,
                    @PathVariable(value = "utvarVSId", required = false) Long utvarVSId) {
...
```

We needed to use path like `.../misc/1` (1), `.../misc/1/25` (2), `.../misc/1/null` (3). Path 1 is represented `/getevidencecounts/{userId}`. path 2 and 3 `/getevidencecounts/{userId}/{utvarVSId = default}`. If you are sure, that default value is null, you can also sustitute in declaration `= default` by `= null` value.